# Add Row after specified <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have a table and a user can add rows. Depending on row type, they are added a little differently. A standard row is always added by .append(), but an "instruction" row should always be added after the last row that was created or modified.

```
//Lastrow is always a Jquery object of a table row that's present on the DOM.
//The variable is set/reset whenever a row is created or modified.
lastRow = $(row)

...
 //indexRow = lastRow, but passed as an argument. 
function addRow(rowType, indexRow){
  newRow="<tr><td>Test</td></tr>";  

  //Want to add the new row after the last created row, and it doesn't work.
  //However if lastRow is an existing row that's been modified, it does work.
  if(rowType =='instructionRow'){
      indexRow.after($(newRow));
      indexRow.get(0).scrollIntoView();
  }

  if(rowType=="normalRow"){
     $('tableId').append(newRow);
     lastRow = $(newRow);
  }
}
```

Some examples of where lastRow is being set

```
//In the add row function itself, if the row is not an instruction row.
//Where newRow = HTML for a table row
//This does not work when you try addRow("instructionRow", lastAddedRow) after it
  if(rowType=="normalRow"){
     lastRow = $(newRow);
  }

//In a row that is updated.
//Where row is a row in the dom, in a .each() loop
//In this case, the addRow("instructionRow", lastRow) will work.
$('tableId tr').each(function (index, row){
    if(row.childNodes[1].innerText == 'whatever'){
        lastRow = $(row);                   
        row.childNodes[1].innerText = "New Value";
}
```

So I can figure newly created rows aren't active dom elements when they're added to lastRow, but not sure why or what to do to get around it.

EDIT: Fiddle:
https://codepen.io/josh-dredge/pen/ZEppyXm?editors=1111

To replicate.

1. Press "Add Normal Row". Two or three times.
2. Press "Add Instruction Row". Nothing will happen (it's meant to)
3. Press "Update Normal Row". The first normal row will update.
   4  Press "Add Instruction Row". An instruction row will now be added after the updated normal row

Comment: Please click `[<>]` and produce a [mcve]

Comment: Added with instructions to replicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your varialble `newRow` is a string, when you do:

```
$('#tableId').append(newRow);
lastRow = $(newRow);
```

it's not the *same* "newRow" - the second line creates a new element (that hasn't been appended to the DOM) by re-parsing the string.

Instead, you could do:

```
lastRow = $(newRow);
$('#tableId').append(lastRow);
```

or

```
lastRow = $(newRow).appendTo('#tableId')
```

both of which will set `lastRow` to the row that has been appended and is in the DOM

Comment: Thanks. Though neither seem to work for me, I am playing around with it. I have added a fiddle in the main post. EDIT: Did get it to work with appendTo(). Cache wasn't reloading for some reason.